# Searching for a value in an array and returning a value in that row/column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am very basic at vba so unfortunately don't have a lot of ideas of how to do this type of search and related call.

I have an array like the below with each cell in the array a number from 0 to 100.

I want to create a table where for every value in the data set above 80, I return the heading from both the column and row of the cell. So at the first iteration the table would look something like this:

**Table example**

a 80 b

c 85 f

e 92 g

**Array**

abcdefghij

a

b

c

d

e

f

g

h

I

j

I think I have been specific but I don't really have a clue where to start. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's *too broad* for SO's format; "specific" means a [mcve] - you need to *research* where to start, *try things*, get stuck with a *specific problem* **that other people might get stuck with too**, and ask about *that specific problem*. Otherwise SO would be "I need XYZ, how do I do that?", and wouldn't be half as useful as it is.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You're totally right, I feel a little bit sorry mate. I had started with a try to give a "start tip" but ended up with somewhat a complete solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you started:

```
Sub CaptureCellsAboveValue(val as double, srcRange as Range, destRange as Range)
    Dim srcRrow as long, srcCol as Long, destRow as Long: destRow = 1
    For srcRow = 2 to srcRange.Rows.Count
        For srcCol = 2 to srcRange.Columns.Count
            If srcRange.Cells(srcRow, srcCol).Value > val Then
                destRange.Cells(destRow, 1).Value = _
                    srcRange.Cells(srcRow, 1).Value & " " & _
                    srcRange.Cells(srcRow, srcCol).Value  & " " & _
                    srcRange.Cells(1, srcCol).Value
                destRow = destRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use it with the parameters:

- Value: 80 in your example
- srcRange: the table range including header row and header columns
- destRange: the Top cell of the range where you want to out those results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips above guys and sorry it was a bad question format.

With some help from a friend I managed to come up with this which does what the question requires. The source range doesn't dynamically define itself which I am learning how to do now.

```
Sub maketable()
Dim rng As Range, i As Single, j As Single
Dim outrow As Single
Set rng = Sheets("Heatmap+").Range("F6:HR226")

outrow = 2

For i = 1 To 221
For j = 1 To 221
    If rng(i, j).Value >= 80 Then

        Sheets("Table").Cells(outrow, 1).Value = rng(i, j).Value
        Sheets("Table").Cells(outrow, 2).Value = Sheets("Heatmap+").Cells(1, j + 1).Value
        Sheets("Table").Cells(outrow, 3).Value = Sheets("Heatmap+").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value



        outrow = outrow + 1
    End If
Next j
Next i
```

Hopefully this can help someone looking for this kind of output from a large array.

-- As part of learning I am trying to make the previous answer work, so thank you for that!